# Unable to split List content with space as delimiter - C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have just started to learn C# for one of my projects, in which i should be able to read all the data from a text file and then i should be able to compare the imported data with the default data structure of the file. So far i have been able to do a little bit of stuff, however i am stuck at splitting the imported data in a list with space as delimiter so that i can try to compare it with the default data which i am planning to put in a default data list.

The structure of the file(File1) to be imported(or the user provided) is as follows:-

```
%emp_first_name% = xxxxxxxx %emp_middle_name% = xxxxxxxx %emp_last_name% = xxxxxxxx;  
%emp_age% = nn;  
%emp_dept.% = xxxxxxxx;  
%emp_joining_date% = xx-xx-xxxx;
```

the default structure of the file(File2) is:-

```
%emp_first_name% = xxxxxxxx %emp_middle_name% = xxxxxxxx %emp_last_name% = xxxxxxxx;  
%emp_age% = nn;  
%emp_total_exp% = xx;  
%emp_grade% = x;  
%emp_dept.% = xxxxxxxx;  
%emp_joining_date% = xx-xx-xxxx;
```

after reading the File1 in a list, i am unable to split it using space as a delimiter, this is what i am doing to read the File1 into a list.

```
    public static void readFinL(string filename)
            {
                string readAllLines = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                list.Add(readAllLines);
                foreach (string d in list)
                {
                    var f = d.Split(',');
                    Console.WriteLine(f.GetValue(0));
                }
            }
```

what am i not doing or what is it that i am  doing incorrectly with this method to read the file in a list. I am passing the data in a list since i should be able to compare File1 with File2 to check which row is missing in File1. Any pointer in correct direction will be helpful.

Comment: Hello, change var f = d.Split(' '); You are splitting using ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `d.Split(',')` is splitting with the comma. Use `var f = d.Split(' ')`  instead.

If I'm not wrong, `File.ReadAllText` return a single string. Your list only have one element by this way.

`string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path to the file")`

Should do the work.